# Is $TN$ a smooth embedded submanifold with or without boundary in $TM$?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with or without boundary, and $N$ a smooth embedded submanifold with or without boundary in $M$, then the inclusion map $N\to M$ induces $TN\to TM$, is $TN$ a smooth embedded submanifold with or  without boundary in $TM$?

Comment: Yes indeed. Just think of what the charts are.